# How to find out the first file executed in an EAR package

Tags: java, jsp, ibm-rad

I need help in finding out first file that will execute when an EAR package runs on localhost. There is no main method in it and there are lot of JSPs and java files in it. I need help on this and the IDE which I am using in RAD by IBM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running in Debugger mode helps us to find it.
Need to identify the JSP and put put debugger points in java files and then restart the server in Debug mode. The control comes to the debugger and then you can proceed with line by line execution using F5/F6.